# How change default method name in intellij idea?

Tags: java, methods, intellij-idea, naming

When shortkey for extracting new method is pressed Idea show a dialog with method name like that - `get + SomeName`. Is there a to change this template to `create + SomeName`?

**Note**

I have already seen that there is a setting `Editor/File and Code templates` but it contains only method bodies, not names.

Answer (score 2):

The way you can change the template for the getters and setters is through the *Generate* menu.

Invoke the menu (`Alt+insert`) and choose *Getter and Setter* (**or** one of *Getter* and *Setter*). If you click the `...` button next to the template selection you can create your own template that does what you want.

In your case you could simply replace the word "`get`" with "`create`" like below to get what you want while retaining everything else from the Intellij default template.

```
public ##
#if($field.modifierStatic)
  static ##
#end
$field.type ##
#set($name = $StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project))))
#if ($field.boolean && $field.primitive)
  #if ($StringUtil.startsWithIgnoreCase($name, 'is'))
    #set($name = $StringUtil.decapitalize($name))
  #else
    is##
#end
#else
  create##
#end
${name}() {
  return $field.name;
}
```

Comment: @Cherry, any feedback on this?